# How do I pass an MVC Model to a Controller action

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, model, controller

I am trying to pass the MVC model object to a Controller Action from JavaScript but it is either `null` or errors, when I have tried things for a over a day now.

The Controller argument JC is always `null`.

My JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {
  $(".dialog-modal").dialog({
    height: 140,
    modal: true
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#job-save").dialog({
    height: 240,
    modal: true
  });
});

$("#job-save").dialog({
  close: function(event, ui) {
    window.location.href = "/EquipmentAll";
  }
});

$(function() {
  $("#ContactKey").change(function() {
    var t = $(this).val();

    if (t !== "") {
      $.post("@Url.Action("GetContactDefaults")?val=" + t + "&JC=" + @Model,
        function(res) {
          if (res.Success === "true") {
            //enable the text boxes and set the value
            $("#ContactEmail").prop('disabled', false).val(res.Data.EmailAddress);
            $("#Height").prop('disabled', false).val(res.Data.Height);
          } else {
            alert("Error getting data!");
          }
        }
      )
    } else {
      //Let's clear the values and disable :)
      $("input.editableItems").val('').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

My Controller action code is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetContactDefaults(string val, JobCreate JC)
{
    //Contact tContact = JC.ContactList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ContactKey == val);
    if (val != "")
    {
        // Values are hard coded for demo. you may replae with values 
        // coming from your db/service based on the passed in value ( val.Value)
        return Json(new { Success = "true", Data = new { EmailAddress = "col@ss", TelAreaCode = 345, TelNo = 100, ACa = "444" } });
    }
    return Json(new { Success = "false" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize your model and insert with `Html.Raw`. I recommend to pass object in POST body instead of GET parameter:

1. In your view, put object to request body:

   ```
   var callback = function(res) {

      if (res.Success === "true") {

       //enable the text boxes and set the value

       $("#ContactEmail").prop('disabled', false).val(res.Data.EmailAddress);
       $("#Height").prop('disabled', false).val(res.Data.Height);

      } else {
       alert("Error getting data!");
      }
    });


   $.post("@Url.Action("GetContactDefaults")?val=" + t, "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))", callback, 'json');
   ```
2. In controller add parameters attributes:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult GetContactDefaults([FromQuery]string val, [FromBody]JobCreate JC)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I am now getting a CS0246 The type or namespace name 'FromQueryAttribute' could not be found. Missing Using directive or Assembly reference? What am I missing here?

Comment: @Col what is your ASP.NET MVC version? Core, 4 or 5?

Comment: @Col try to change FromQuery to FromUri or leave `string val` without attribute

Comment: System.Web.Mvc in config is 5.2.3.0

Comment: I did get it to process further by removing the attribute.However it now crashes - I think because there is an @ sign in the json encoded data but will look further.